# firefox making white "flash" as it builds the page

Tags: javascript, html, flash, firefox

Ive been working on building a website with a flash slideshow component, and I am a little bit puzzled.  When I view the page in Firefox (3.6.8), it appears to download the content of the page first and makes a white "flash" as it downloads the slideshow.  But when I view the page in Safari it appears to build the page first, then download the slideshow, so there is no white "flash".  Also in Chrome, once the content is cached, it doesn't make the flash, but I still get the flash in Firefox everytime.

http://paxtoncreative.com -- click on the portfolio link and choose any of the 3 galleries.

At least, I think thats what going on.

If this is the case, is there a way to force Firefox on the users browser to behave differently, and build the page first?

I may be misunderstanding whats happening with the page, but I think I remember hearing that Safari builds the page in a different order than Firefox.

I'm open to other ideas as well; I understand that I could be way off base with this thought.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right path, different browsers render pages in different order and that is why sometimes you get the "white" flash and some times you don't.

One way to make the experience a little bit better is to make the flash background color for the stage similar to the background color of your HTML page. Since you don't have a solid color you have to get a similar "green" color that you already using.

You still will get a slight "flash" but it wont be black but green and should be closer to the green you are using.

Comment: thanks for the info.  glad I have somewhere to start now.  me and the customer are planning on implementing an ajax driven content site soon so I would think that would cut down on the "flash".

thanks again.