# Firefox white flash upon certain javascript events

Tags: javascript, firefox, redraw

This is similar to this question: ([firefox-making-white-flash-as-it-builds-the-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451602/firefox-making-white-flash-as-it-builds-the-page))  But the difference is that in my situation, that page is already fully loaded.

Well after the page has fully loaded, on certain javascript events that trigger adding elements to my page, Firefox produces a white flash (not over the entire page, but not on the specific div where the elements are being added) covering a large area of the page (basically it happens to an ancestor of the div I am adding content to, but it is not the direct ancestor).

The elements I'm adding are in a horizontally scrolling div,  so its not like the page width gets changed at all. Also, it is not consistent. Sometimes the adding or removing elements triggers the white flash, and other times it does not.

I'm assuming this is just an issue with the way FF redraws the page.

I know my question may be a little vague, but I wasn't sure if anyone has had experience with this or has any suggestions. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen in other browsers?

Comment: Couple things you may want to add - 1) How large is the event listener adding the scrolling div 2) Specify which DOM events you are listening to. Both points go to potential performance related issues (forcing FF to redraw too often etc)

Comment: @Nick - I've tried IE8 Chrome and FF.  Only happens in FF.  The others work fine.

Comment: @Shakakai What do you mean by "How Large?"  Basically, There are elements already in the scrolling div. If you click on a particular element (onclick listener)  I add more elements that are related to the element you clicked. I'm not convinced its performanced based because IE has no issue drawing out the new elements.  And from other research I've done, other people complain about white flashes in FF. I was just hoping there might be some sort of a solution.

Comment: there are certain properties in FF that force a redraw immediately after you change them - if you use enough of them in a single event handler that could cause the problem. For example in FF, if you toggle visible to false and then back to true that would force two redraw events immediately when run as opposed to batch processing that normally occurs (with other DOMElement properties).

Comment: Do you append any elements before they are all created?